# Concerning the closedness of a subset of $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was reading some stuff about that involved $L^p$ spaces and came up with this question: Given $X=L^1[0,1]$, I need to show a closed, convex subset of a Banach space with some properties, the thing is that apparently the the set 
$$\mathcal{C}=\left\{f\in X:\int_0^1fdx=1\right\}$$
 is closed, and I just can't make sense of it, so there may be something I'm missing. Convexity is not a problem at all but the closed part.

For instance, take the sequence 
$$f_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}n&x\in[0,1/n]\\0&x\in[1/n,1]\end{array}\right. $$
 so $\displaystyle\int f_ndx=1$ for all $n$, but I'm kind of sure that there is no $f\in X$ such that $$||f_n-f||_1\to0$$ as $n\to\infty$ so I'm sort of stuck here. Any hints will be very well appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your functions $f_n$ do not converge to anything in $L^1.$ So it's a nonexample.

Comment: ups, my bad, I got confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Lf = \int_{0}^{1}fdx$ defines a continuous function $L : L^1[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ because $|Lf| \le \|f\|_{L^1}$. Therefore, $\mathcal{C}=L^{-1}\{1\}$ is closed because $\{1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ if your problem and space are over $\mathbb{R}$ instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be such a function $f$? The set $[-1,1]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. However, the sequence $\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge there.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n \to f$ and $\int f_n= 1$ then
$|\int f - 1| = | \int (f-f_n)| \le \int |f-f_n| = \|f-f_n\|$. Hence
$\int f = 1$.